# SwingWorker doInbackground finished after one iteration only

Tags: java, swing

I dont know what I am doing wrong here. I am iterating over a list in my doInBackground method but the loop always exits at the first iteration.

```
 class ScreenerDataLoader extends SwingWorker<Void,Integer> {

    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        List<TickerStatistics> tickers = rc.getAll24HrPriceStatistics();    //2000 items

        progressBar.setMaximum(tickers.size());
        for(int i=0; i< tickers.size();i++){
            System.out.println(i);  //logs 0 then done is fired
            markets.add(new Market(tickers.get(i).getSymbol(),timeframe));
            publish(markets.size());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
       progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size()-1));
    }

    protected void done() {
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was actually the reason it didnt run through. I thought the exception would get thrown anyways. Now I know why, my markets List wasnt initialized :)

Answer (score 0):

Always call the `get()` method of the `SwingWorker` when it has finished, even if no result is expected. This can be added to the `done()` method.

If the `doInBackground()` method terminated with some Exception, the `get()` method will throw an `ExecutionException` with more details. If `get()` is not called, the Exception will go unnoticed.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get()) of `get()` has a hint:

> **Throws:**
> . . .
> `ExecutionException` - if the computation threw an exception